# Cycle Through Dictionary to Pull Out 2 Values

Tags: python, rest, dictionary, tuples

I am working on a project with a piece of robotic equipment (self driving robotic cart accessed through rest protocol). This code receives data from the robot about 'missions' that are programmed within the robot that I would like to access and sort by name and GUID without the other information that is not needed. 
I think I am working with a dictionary of items but I am not very familiar with dictionaries at all. Here is a piece of the data I am receiving and need to sort through:

```
{u'guid': u'01b735d6-4a8e-11e7-b126-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'Spraying demo'}, {u'guid': u'00d5387c-4b7d-11e7-9221-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'REST Mission'}, {u'guid': u'f47be478-4c28-11e7-b184-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'Am or demo'}, {u'guid': u'e1af13ba-4f38-11e7-9626-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'Demo - Tech Center'}
```

I would like to pull out all items which are guid's or names. If possible, my goal is to get them out in separate lists (like a list of guid's and a list of names).

Here is my code attempting to handle this (I apologize, it may be sloppy):

```
demo = 'e1af13ba-4f38-11e7-9626-f44d3061db09'

def compMissionQueue():
    getMissionQueue = robot.get_mission_queue()[1][0]
    missionID = getMissionQueue['id']
    missionGUID = robot.get_mission_GUID_from_queue(missionID)[1]['mission_id']
    if missionGUID != mission:
        print('Adding mission to queue')

    else:
        print('Mission already in queue. Add again? Y or N')  

def loadMission():          #Loads mission to robot queue and continues robot operation
        runDemo = robot.load_mission(demo)
        #robot.continue_robot()
        #robot.pause_robot()
        #robot.delete_from_mission_queue(demo)
        global mission
        mission = demo

def cycleMissions():        #Cycles through mission names and GUID's
    getAllMissions()
    #while True:
        #getMissions += 1


def getAllMissions():       #Returns list of all missions in robot
    getMissions = robot.get_missions()[1][5]['guid']
    print(getMissions)

def techDemo():
    compMissionQueue()
    #loadMission()
    #print(mission)
```

I have tried to find the solution and I see a lot of people doing things like

`for k in dict: 
print (k)`

But that doesn't do what I am trying to do. I imported the data as a variable named getMissions. I can get it to pull out a single item by narrowing it down like a tuple with the brackets but the number of items in the dictionary change so I would have to constantly update the code every time a new item was added. If you have any advice, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with list comprehension:

```
l = [{u'guid': u'01b735d6-4a8e-11e7-b126-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'Spraying demo'}, {u'guid': u'00d5387c-4b7d-11e7-9221-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'REST Mission'}, {u'guid': u'f47be478-4c28-11e7-b184-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'Am or demo'}, {u'guid': u'e1af13ba-4f38-11e7-9626-f44d3061db09', u'name': u'Demo - Tech Center'}]
names = [d['name'] for d in l]
guids = [d['guid'] for d in l]
print(names)
print(guids)
```

Output:

```
['Spraying demo', 'REST Mission', 'Am or demo', 'Demo - Tech Center']
['01b735d6-4a8e-11e7-b126-f44d3061db09', '00d5387c-4b7d-11e7-9221-f44d3061db09', 'f47be478-4c28-11e7-b184-f44d3061db09', 'e1af13ba-4f38-11e7-9626-f44d3061db09']
```

Explanation:

`[d['name'] for d in l]` will iterate through the list of dictionaries and build a list of dictionary values that have the key `'name'`.